# Convert string to List so square bracket will be eliminated and will be a list

Tags: python, list

```
'[1, 2]'
```

It is a string. How to I make it List `[1,2]`

So convertion from `'[1, 2]'` to `[1,2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options

[eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

```py
eval('[1, 2]')
# [1, 2]
```

[ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```py
import ast
ast.literal_eval('[1, 2]')
# [1, 2]
```

string parsing

```py
list(map(int, '[1, 2]'.strip('[]').split(', ')))
# [1, 2]
```